# Allow foreign key fields in Django Admin forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Right now I have two models: Inventory and Item

An Item can have multiple Inventory transactions (you can think of these essentially as batches), but an Inventory transaction can have only one item, so one-to-many relationship, right? Anyway, I'm using a foreign key field like so:

**models.py**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    description     = models.TextField()
    brand           = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Inventory(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name="inventory")
```

The workflow right now is that I create an item in ItemAdmin, but I have no access to add Inventory (batches) from there. So, I have to exit and go to InventoryAdmin to add actual inventory. The good thing here is I'm allowed a dropdown in the InventoryAdmin to link the Inventory I'm creating to the Item I first created, before I save the InventoryAdmin form.

I'm hoping however, that there's a way when I first create that Item that I can link it to an Inventory Transaction as to make the workflow more streamlined. I had the concern that given the foreign key relationship, I can't add an Inventory Transaction to an Item I haven't yet created. If there's a workaround, I'd like to know, and if possible, I'd like to figure a way to prevent (or toggle between) auth users the ability to edit an item after it's been added.

Below is a way to make it so after I create an Inventory Transaction and link it to an Item, that if I go back and try to edit the Item, it won't let me, but I'd like to disable to ability to edit it with the pencil icon in the form altogether.

Here's my admin.py, thank you:

```
class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'description', 'brand')


class InventoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Inventory
        fields = '__all__'

class InventoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = InventoryForm
    readonly_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at')
    list_display = ('id', 'item', 'active',  'description')

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj:
            return ['item']
        else:
            return []
```

Answer (score -1):

use the double underscore to traverse the foreign key tree

```
list_display = ('id', 'item', 'item__description', 'item__brand',  'active',  'description')
```

Comment: I tried that, but got this: ERRORS:
<class 'apps.ecommerce_app.admin.InventoryAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[2]' refers to 'item__brand', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'InventoryAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'ecommerce_app.Inventory'. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I think it has sth to do with registering. Please show the code in which you make admin.site.register

Comment: admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)
admin.site.register(Inventory, InventoryAdmin)

Comment: Replace form = InventoryForm with model = Inventory

Comment: Okay. try unregistering and register again